# CFG to define a language

Tags: compiler-construction, computer-science, context-free-grammar

I need to generate a context free grammar for this language L= { a^i b^j c^k | i, j, k ≥ 0 , i = j or i = k }

what I already have is 
S : aSc | T | abS
T : bT | cT | ԑ

Do you guys think that the above grammar can correctly define the language? if not, is there any better suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

No, that grammar does not correctly define the language. It accepts "bc", for instance.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I can generate two grammars, one for  i = j  and the other for i = k, then combine both grammars to define the language.